# How to parse correctly an argument with foward slash in bash?

Tags: bash, git, repo

I wrote a script in which I try to wrap some AOSP `repo` commands. One of the arguments I pass to the script is a branch in the following format: `refs/tags/NAME`.

When I pass this directly to `repo init`, it resolves just fine. However, when I pass to my script, I get the error: `fatal: Couldn't find remote ref refs/tags/NAME`

Below is my script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

URL='private url ommited'
# initially, I tried just to BRANCH=$3 which didn't work either
BRANCH=`echo $3 | sed 's!/!\/!g'`
MANIFEST="$5"
REPO_URL='another private url ommited'
REPO_BRANCH='ommited'

# point to objects
repo init -u $URL -b $BRANCH -m $MANIFEST --repo-url=$REPO_URL --repo-branch=$REPO_BRANCH --depth=1

# download code
time repo sync --no-tags
```

First I assumed the issue was related to "/" and tried to sed it with "\/", but I get the same error. Now I assume there is some bash logic I don't understand correctly.

For now, we can assume that branch will always be the third argument and manifest the fifth. In the future, I may refactor this. Also, this is pure bash and will just run on this particular machine.

**EDIT:**

I've just run the script with `/bin/bash -x` and my variable `BRANCH` is returning `refs/tags/NAME` as it should, but the `repo init` command doesn't seem to recognize when the variable `BRANCH` is expanded to `refs/tags/NAME`. In fact, if I pass the `"$3"` directly to `repo init`, it doesn't work either.

I also tried to pass the whole arguments array `"$@"` as the other variables allocated in the script, such as `URL`, `MANIFEST` and others also passed to the scripts, but the `repo init` command doesn't interpret it correctly also (which seems related to the URL and what led me to believe that foward slashes where the one responsible for this issue).

All my tries where made by the following steps:

- create a new directory
- `cd` to it
- try to run the script and notice the fail
- `rm -rf .repo`
- `repo init` with the same arguments

Comment: Does quoting help? e.g. `repo init -u "$URL" -b "$BRANCH" -m "$MANIFEST" --repo-url="$REPO_URL" --repo-branch="$REPO_BRANCH" --depth=1` This would mostly matter if `ref/tags/NAME` can have characters used for word splitting (spaces, tabs, newlines) or filename expansion (e.g. asterisks, square brackets), or perhaps if the URL can be misinterpreted as such.

Comment: You don't need `sed`; nothing is trying to interpret forward slashes in any special fashion, though you *should* be quoting all your parameter expansions. What value are you setting `BRANCH` to in the first place? Should it be `NAME`, not `refs/tags/NAME`?

Comment: A quick test for quoting issues is to run the script with `/bin/bash -x` or add `set -x` to the script and examine the output of the `repo init` command. If the contents of a variable are being misinterpreted the debug output can make it easier to see how it's being misinterpreted exactly ("misinterpreted" meaning relative to your expectations).

Comment: Given that this is Bash, a straightforward `${3//\//\\/}` is better for replacing strings than piping via external `sed`.  If it were actually needed.

Comment: This doesn't look like a bash issue, but a `repo` issue. Are you in the right directory when you run this script?

Comment: @tjm3772 I forgot to mention that I tried to double quote and also wrapping in {}, but the same error still occurs. About the `-x`, I'll do just that.

@chepner the `sed` was in fact an alternative I tried it because the above didn't work, but in fact it's really not needed for the issue to be reproduced

@glennjackman yep, I'm in right directory. As I said, running my script outputs the error, running the `repo init` with the same arguments does not

Comment: @chepner the `BRANCH` variable should be `refs/tags/NAME`. This is always the third argument in the command I use, that's why I'm storing it from `"$3"` (and from my code, the output from `sed`). I'll edit my post with more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just found the solution for this issue. I think that repo might have some issue with bash expansion or I just don't really get what was going wrong.

However, to solve this I used the below:

```bash
INIT=$(eval echo $@)

repo init -u $INIT
```

Instead passing the `$@` directly to `repo init` command or setting the variables by hand. Just `echo $@` didn't work either.